# Replace elements in an object and array?

Tags: javascript

If I draw from the object y, for example 'JPY 20, USD 20', I want to replace the USD and JPY abbreviation with the extended name DOLLAR and JEN. It has to look like this:
'JPY 20, USD 20' replace to 'JEN 20, DOLLAR 20'

```
var x = {
    'U': 'DOLLAR',
    'J': 'JEN',
    'E': 'EURO'
};


var  y = [
    'U 50',
    'J 20, U 20',
    'E 20, J 10'
];

var z = y[Math.floor(Math.random() * y.length)]; //example 'JPY 20, USD 20'

for(var key in x) {
    var c = new RegExp({key}, "g");
    z = z.replace(key, x[key]);  
    console.log(z);      //It should looks like //'JEN 20, DOLLAR 20'
}
```

```js
var x = { U: 'DOLLAR', J: 'JEN', E: 'EURO' },
    y = ['U 50', 'J 20, U 20', 'E 20, J 10'],
    z = y[Math.floor(Math.random() * y.length)],
    key,
    regex;

for (key in x) {
    regex = new RegExp(key, "g");
    z = z.replace(regex, x[key]);  
}  

console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coudl take all strings for replacement and join it with pipe for aleternative searches and replace with the new value.

```js
var array = ['U 50', 'J 20, U 20', 'E 20, J 10'],
    replacements = { U: 'DOLLAR', J: 'JEN', E: 'EURO' },
    string = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)],
    regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(replacements).join('|'), "g");

string = string.replace(regex, key => replacements[key]);  

console.log(string);
```

Comment: How should I set regex if  var x = { U: 'DOLLAR', J: 'JEN', E: 'EURO' },
    y = ['U 50', 'J 20, U 20', 'E 20, J 10']; Random 'J 20, U 20'; console.log return "EURO 20, JEURON 10"

Comment: just take the same code. the lenght of the replacement strings is not importent unless they are unique.

Comment: console.log return JEURON instead JEN